# Keyboard input not working after Scene restart in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a simple game, with only one scene, whenever the player dies i call this.scene.restart()

But after i restart the game the keyboard input is not working anymore and there's no error in the console

I'm using this in create() function to set the keyboard

this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

Any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include your code for setting up the key handlers?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me in the same situation:

```
game.destroy(true, false);
game.canvas.parentNode.removeChild(game.canvas); //removes the old game canvas
game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

I admit, it's not really suitable for professional use.